# How to get the click through URL of native custom template ad

Tags: android, google-dfp

I am implementing native custom template ad in my android app and below is the code I am using for fetching and rendering custom template ad in my view. I want to open the a webview when user clicks on the ad with the click through URL that I set in my dfp portal but I don't see any method or documentation on how to get hold of that URL. Please help me with this

```
private void fetchAd(final View convertView, final int position) {

       templateAdLoadedListener = new NativeCustomTemplateAd.OnCustomTemplateAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCustomTemplateAdLoaded(NativeCustomTemplateAd nativeCustomTemplateAd) {
                        populateAd(nativeCustomTemplateAd, convertView);
                        nativeCustomTemplateAd.recordImpression();
                    }
                };

                templateAdClickListener = new NativeCustomTemplateAd.OnCustomClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCustomClick(NativeCustomTemplateAd nativeCustomTemplateAd, String s) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AboutWebActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("TYPE", "AD");
                        intent.putExtra("TITLE", nativeCustomTemplateAd.getText("Advertiser"));
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCustomClick: s = " + s);
                        intent.putExtra("URL","url will go here");
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                };
                adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(context, ad_unit_id)
                        .forCustomTemplateAd(ad_template_id, templateAdLoadedListener, templateAdClickListener)
                        .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onCustomTemplateAdFailedToLoad: error code");
                            }
                        }).build();

                adLoader.loadAd(new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by sending the click-through-URL as a text from DFP server as an ad asset.

You can get reference to that URL using the method

`CharSequence calltoactionURL = nativeCustomTemplateAd.getText(AdConstants.DFP_CALL_TO_ACTION_URL);`

Now you can use this value to perform any operation.